# Defining the electric field with a potential in axisymmetric, stationary fluids on Kerr black hole spacetime

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, black-holes, kerr-metric

So studying the RMHD (relativistic magnetohydrodynamics) equations of a fluid (/plasma) and specifically Maxwell's equation reads as

$$ \nabla \times E = - \dfrac{1}{c} \dfrac{\partial B}{\partial t}  = 0 $$ which results in a potential for the quantity $\vec{E}$

$$E = -\nabla V(r,z)$$

In Kerr Black Hole metric, following the 3+1 formalism:

$$D_\tau\tilde{B}-\tilde{\sigma}\cdot\tilde{B}=-\tilde\nabla\times\tilde{E}+\tilde{E}\times\tilde{a}$$

(by Thorne & Macdonald (1982))

and equilevant $$ L_\beta B + \nabla \times (NE) = 0  $$

where N is the lapse function and $\beta$ is the shift vector.

which gives no obvious quantities $A(E,a),B(E,a)$ thats satisfies the relationship $$A = -\nabla B$$

I have searched the literature but with no results. Any clue?

Comment: Depends on your gauge. I would start with a four-vector potential $A_\mu$ such that $A_{\mu,\nu} - A_{\nu,mu} = F_{\mu\nu}$ and work from there. (B and E have definitions in terms of projections of $F_{\mu\nu}$ into the 3+1 frame.) Of course, if you do *ideal* magnetohydrodynamics, that is a completely different story.

Comment: @Void These are Maxwell Equations, it should not be dependant on weather its idear or not (like in SRMHD). In my analysis i keep a resistive term . So I'm guessing there is no literature right? I knew there should be a way around with Fμ∋ but did not try it. I also posted another equation form which shows the term that messes things up. Anyways I guess I will go from start